# What's the list of Hidden Abilites for Fire Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

The Ability Capsule can be used to switch between two abilites, right? I wondered if I could use this for my Charizard with Blaze.. Unless it doesn't have a hidden ability to switch to.

Comment: Ow, why the downvote? I checked if this was a duplicate, at least I tried.

Comment: Also, Bulbapedia only lists a general list, I want a list of Fire Pokemon in particular. https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_with_released_Hidden_Abilities_(Generation_VII)

Comment: To switch to a Hidden Ability, you’d need an [Ability Patch](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ability_Patch). However, this was not released until Generation 8 (Sword/Shield)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect this was either or both: (1) a lack of research effort or (2) the question in the text and title not aligning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charizard's standard ability is Blaze, while its hidden one is Solar Power.

[Ability Capsule](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ability_Capsule) changes a Pokémon's Ability **from one of its standard Abilities to its other standard Ability**.

The Ability Capsule can only be used on a Pokémon that belongs to a species that has two standard Abilities. And Charizard does not.